# Sharepoint Intranet Branding : How to rollout the changes for themes

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-branding

I have created a new theme as per the corporate guidelines and stapled the same with the site defination, as all the custom themes are unghosted, what is the best way to rollout changes.

is there any option to make the custom theme ghosted, this would make the job much more easier :)

I have found below tool to do that, but I would like to avoid these kind of solutions

BrandingTool (http://www.codeplex.com/BrandingTool)

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2008/01/30/SharePoint-2007-Design-Tip-Import-your-CSS-for-SharePoint-Themes.aspx

cool hack :)